# Function call doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to execute a function that alerts an array but it doesn't work. When I press the Add button, I'm supposed to have an alert containing Lat/lng, but no alert appears.

You can see my working code here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agr3a07m/145/). Press the Add button to see the phenomenon. I call the function `f()` in *line 195* but I don't get anything.

My HTML code:

```
<div id="info"></div>
<div id="dvMap"></div>
<div id="directions_panel" style="margin:20px;background-color:#FFEE77;"></div>
<div id="wrapper">Paste coordinate data here:
    <form onSubmit="javascript:return false;">
        <textarea id="Coords" cols="50" rows="25"></textarea>
        <div>
            <input type="button" id="btnAdd" class="Button" value="Add Markers" onClick="ProcessData()">
            <input type="button" id="btnClear" class="Button" value="Clear Map" onClick="Clear()">
        </div>
        <br>
    </form>
</div>
```

My Javascript code:

```
var directionsDisplay = [];
var directionsService = [];
var map = null;
var g = [];
var path = new Array();
var routeSegment = 0;
var k = 0;

function inizialise() {

    var mapOptions = {

        center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.730166863, 130.7446296584),
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dvMap'), mapOptions);
    document.getElementById("Coords").value = '33.29702, 130.54948000000002' + '\n' + '33.29764, 130.54986000000002' + '\n' + '33.29793, 130.55010000000001' + '\n' + '33.298730000000006, 130.55066000000002' + '\n' + '33.299620000000004, 130.55129000000002'

    // calcRoute() ;

}
var MyArray = [];

function Clear() {
    //alert(directionsDisplay.length);

    MyArray = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < directionsDisplay.length; i++) {
        directionsDisplay[i].setMap(null);
    }
    //  directionsDisplay = [];
    document.getElementById("Coords").value = "";
    document.getElementById("Coords").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("btnAdd").disabled = false;

}

function ProcessData() {
    var Points = document.getElementById("Coords").value

    if (document.getElementById("Coords").value != '') {
        var Points = document.getElementById("Coords").value
        calcRoute(Points);
    }

}
/*
function ProcessData() {
    alert('ok');
    if (document.getElementById("Coords").value != '') {
        var Points = document.getElementById("Coords").value
        AddMarkers(Points); 
    }

}*/


function AddMarkers(data) {

    var MyData = data.substr(0, data.length);
    MyArray = MyData.split("\n");
    //alert(MyArray[2]);
    // calcRoute();
    t();
}


function calcRoute(data) {
    var MyData = data.substr(0, data.length);
    MyArray = MyData.split("\n");
    var input_msg = MyArray;
    var locations = new Array();


    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0; i < input_msg.length; i++) {
        var tmp_lat_lng = input_msg[i].split(",");
        //var s = new google.maps.LatLng(tmp_lat_lng[0], tmp_lat_lng[1]);
        locations.push(new google.maps.LatLng(tmp_lat_lng[0], tmp_lat_lng[1]));
        bounds.extend(locations[locations.length - 1]);
    }

    /* var mapOptions = {
        // center: locations[0],
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dvMap'), mapOptions);
    */
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    var summaryPanel = document.getElementById("directions_panel");
    summaryPanel.innerHTML = "";
    var i = locations.length;
    var index = 0;

    while (i != 0) {

        if (i < 3) {
            var tmp_locations = new Array();
            for (var j = index; j < locations.length; j++) {
                tmp_locations.push(locations[j]);
            }
            drawRouteMap(tmp_locations);
            i = 0;
            index = locations.length;
        }

        if (i >= 3 && i <= 10) {
            console.log("before :fun < 10: i value " + i + " index value" + index);
            var tmp_locations = new Array();
            for (var j = index; j < locations.length; j++) {
                tmp_locations.push(locations[j]);
            }
            drawRouteMap(tmp_locations);
            i = 0;
            index = locations.length;
            console.log("after fun < 10: i value " + i + " index value" + index);
        }

        if (i >= 10) {
            console.log("before :fun > 10: i value " + i + " index value" + index);
            var tmp_locations = new Array();
            for (var j = index; j < index + 10; j++) {
                tmp_locations.push(locations[j]);
            }
            drawRouteMap(tmp_locations);
            i = i - 9;
            index = index + 9;
            console.log("after fun > 10: i value " + i + " index value" + index);
        }
    }
}
var coord = new Array();

function drawRouteMap(locations) {

    var start, end;
    var waypts = [];

    for (var k = 0; k < locations.length; k++) {
        if (k >= 1 && k <= locations.length - 2) {
            waypts.push({
                location: locations[k],
                stopover: true
            });
        }
        if (k == 0) start = locations[k];

        if (k == locations.length - 1) end = locations[k];

    }
    var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        waypoints: waypts,
        optimizeWaypoints: false,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    console.log(request);

    directionsService.push(new google.maps.DirectionsService());
    var instance = directionsService.length - 1;
    directionsDisplay.push(new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        preserveViewport: true
    }));
    directionsDisplay[instance].setMap(map);
    directionsService[instance].route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            console.log(status);
            directionsDisplay[instance].setDirections(response);
            var f = response.routes[0];
           // var summaryPanel = document.getElementById("directions_panel");
            var route = directionsDisplay[instance].getDirections().routes[0];
            // var routes = response.routes;
            var points = route.overview_path;
            //alert(points);
            var ul = document.getElementById("directions_panel");


               var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
            for (i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
                var steps = legs[i].steps;
                for (j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
                    var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
                    for (k = 0; k < nextSegment.length; k++) {
                       // alert(nextSegment[k]);
                        var li = document.createElement('P');
                li.innerHTML = getLatLng(nextSegment[k]);
                ul.appendChild(li);
                       // polyline.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
                        //bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);
                   coord.push( getLatLng(nextSegment[k]));
                      f(coord);   

                    }
                }

            }




        } else {
            alert("directions response " + status);
        }


    });
}

 function f( r) {

    alert(r);
} 

function getLatLng(point) {

//alert(MyArray.length);

    var lat = point.lat(),
        lng = point.lng();
    var tmp = MyArray[k].split(",");
    //  alert(  Math.abs(parseFloat(tmp[0]- lat)) )
    if (Math.abs(parseFloat(tmp[0] - lat)) < 0.00009 && Math.abs(parseFloat(tmp[1] - lng)) < 0.00009) {
        k++;
        // alert(k);
//if(k==MyArray.length) { f('animation');  }
        return " { \"lat\": " + lat + " ,\"lng\" : " + lng + " ,\"waypoint\" : 1},";
    } else {
        return " { \"lat\": " + lat + " ,\"lng\" : " + lng + " ,\"waypoint\" : 0},";
    }
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', inizialise);
```

The problematic code is in line 195: I call `f(coord)`, but the alert doesn't appear. I have defined the `f` function as such:

```js
 function f(r) {
    alert(r);
}
```

Comment: The title for this question is absolutely dreadful.

Comment: The complete [**but minimal**](/help/mcve) code for your question must be **in** your question, not just linked, not even to jsFiddle. Links rot, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. As you've seen, we have Stack Snippets so you can create real demos of the problems you're having with JavaScript.

Comment: possibly you're calling the function before it is created, run it when the page load is complete

Comment: @Backhandx In your fiddle, you have a space, like this: `function ( r)`. Is that the problem?

Comment: I really am so sorry. I edited my question.

Comment: I've rolled back your question to the original - you've already accepted an answer for your original problem, don't edit the question to an entirely different one, because that will make the answer useless to readers. Create a new question instead. Please read: [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder : I edited my code and fixed the problem by myself. I still cannot post other Questions. is it normal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting `f` with an object in line 173:

```
var f = response.routes[0];
```

So when you try to call `f`, it's not a function, but an object (try logging `typeof f` before the call: you will get 'object').

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the reminder, it's a good point. I've cleaned up the question a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problem. I edite my function 'getLatLng()' such as :

```js
function getLatLng(point, array) {
    //alert(k);
    var lat = point.lat(),
        lng = point.lng();
    var tmp = MyArray[k].split(",");
    //  alert(  Math.abs(parseFloat(tmp[0]- lat)) )
    if (Math.abs(parseFloat(tmp[0] - lat)) < 0.00009 && Math.abs(parseFloat(tmp[1] - lng)) < 0.00009) {
        k++;
        array.push({
        "lat": lat ,
         "lng": lng,
         "stop":1
        });
        return " { \"lat\": " + lat + " ,\"lng\" : " + lng + " ,\"waypoint\" : 1},";
    } else {
        
        array.push({
        "lat": lat ,
         "lng": lng,
         "stop":1
        });
        return " { \"lat\": " + lat + " ,\"lng\" : " + lng + " ,\"waypoint\" : 0},";
    }

}
```

Now I can acess to the element of my array. Here my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/agr3a07m/154/)